# iOS UITextView HTML: center image

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to load html content in UITextView in my iOS app.

I use the following html code:

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Sample text.</h3>
<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="182" height="44"/></p>
```

So it should display both the text and the image in the center, however, the image is not centered:

[image]

---

**Does anybody know how I can align the image to center?**

Here is how I set the html content:

```
extension Data {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options:options, documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
extension String {
    var data: Data {
        return Data(utf8)
    }
}
```

...

```
txtIntro.attributedText = htmlStr.data.attributedString
```

Thanks,
Osman

Comment: Note that <center> is deprecated HTML5. Even though it wouldn't make a difference when creating your attributedText it would be better to just add text-align canter to your paragraph `<p style="text-align: center;">` instead.

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. Hovewer, `<p style="text-align: center;">` does not work with images, do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: Yes you can use css and a div instead of a paragraph

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't work. Do you have an example?

Comment: `<style type=\"text/css\">#imgdiv{width: 100%; text-align: center;}</style><div id="imgdiv"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="182" height="44"/></div>`

Comment: Thanks. I might be a valid html/css, however in UITextView it does not center the image. Could you try that and see if it works for you in UITextView?

Comment: I did try and it worked try `<div style="text-align: center;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="182" height="44"/></div>`

Comment: or try adding 100% width to your div `<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"  ><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="182" height="44"/></div>` https://www.dropbox.com/s/s997fls16hl0178/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-04%20at%206.55.35%20PM.png?dl=1

Comment: Thanks, @LeoDabus, it worked. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it. This is better answer, since the other one suggests using a deprecated tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your image inside a div, set its style to center and width to 100%

```
let htmlStr = """
<meta charset=utf-8>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Sample text.</h3>
<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="182" height="44"/></div>
"""
```

Comment: Can you please give another solution to wrap text around the image. if text is multi line and image is right align, so the text gets down below the image.

Answer (score 2):

Around the `<img>` tag in the HTML code make a `<center>` element

```
<center><img src="..."/></center>
```